# Implementing a sortable Image collection not working in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, jquery-ui-sortable

Implementing a sortable Image collection doesn't work

```
<template name="gallery">
  <div id="grid-container" class="cbp-l-grid-agency grid">
    {{#each images getCurrentCategory}}
    {{> image}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

```
Template.gallery.created = function(){
    Tracker.autorun(function () {
        Meteor.subscribe('images'), self.limit.get()
    });
}
Template.gallery.rendered = function(){
    //// Image reordering /////
     this.$('#Images').sortable({
        stop: function(e, ui) {
          el = ui.item.get(0)
          before = ui.item.prev().get(0)
          after = ui.item.next().get(0)
          if(!before) {
            newRank = Blaze.getData(after).rank - 1
          } else if(!after) {
            newRank = Blaze.getData(before).rank + 1
          }
          else
            newRank = (Blaze.getData(after).rank +
                       Blaze.getData(before).rank)/2
          Images.update({_id: Blaze.getData(el)._id}, {$set: {rank: newRank}})
        }
    })
}
Template.gallery.helpers({
    'getCurrentCategory': 
        function() {
        return Template.instance().currentcategory.get();
      },
    'category': function(){
        var allImages = Images.find().fetch();
        var categoryList = _.uniq(allImages, false, function(d) {return d.category});
        var a = _.pluck(categoryList, "category");
        return a;
    },   
    'images': function (currentcategory) {
      if(currentcategory == 'all' || !currentcategory){
        return Images.find({},{sort: {rank: -1}});
     } 
     return Images.find({category:currentcategory});
    }
});
```

What else need to be added or to be modified in the code ?

Comment: http://codepen.io/sangeeth5320/pen/QywjVL?editors=101

Comment: The code is not that long, you can post it here and append a link, it'll be better.

Comment: It seems you have outsourced data crucial for the understanding of your question. Please post all relevant code, images and resources **in the question itself**, if the link dies or changes your question will lose most if not all of its meaning! You can [edit] your question to include the needed informations. Also, can you elaborate on how your code doesn't work? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Comment: @kyll In the gallery.rendered function replaced  `this.$('#Images').sortable` with `this.$('#grid-container).sortable` . and it works since Images is a collection name whereas **grid-container** is the **id** name to be used .

Comment: What template library are you using? What does this has to do with meteor?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, we do not have:

- the collection named Images
- the template named image

And from what I have, I can say :

- Template.gallery.rendered should be renammed into Template.gallery.onRendered(function(){...});
- In your rendered function, you call `sortable`. If you want to manipulate the DOM with a library, it *may be the issue*. Try to do it using only blaze, and then you can test to see if your library is ok with blaze.
- Meteor.subscribe('images') can be call only 1 time

Comment: Since I have Image collection and Template named image in two different files that not included here . so that might not be a problem ..

Can you elaborate how to use that sortable into the onRendered function . And also with blaze how to test . 

A small piece of could would be appreciated .

Comment: Problem resolved. 
rectified code in  http://codepen.io/sangeeth5320/pen/wMBmbb

In sortable function instead of using div class name used the collection name . that's the issue previously .