# How to implement Image reordering in meteor.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, meteor

Need to implement *sortable functionality* in Image Collection . Used rank value to sort the images ..  For all categories it works .. 
If images are categorized by category name it doesn't work ..

How to proceed further for *different categories*

**Gallery.html**

```
<div id="grid-container" class="cbp-l-grid-agency grid">
     {{#each images getCurrentCategory}}
          {{> image}}
     {{/each}}
     {{> addInfo}} 
</div>
```

**Gallery.js**

```
Template.gallery.rendered = function(){
     this.$('#grid-container').sortable({
         stop: function(e, ui) {
              el = ui.item.get(0)
              before = ui.item.prev().get(0)
              after = ui.item.next().get(0)
              if(!before) {
                  newRank = Blaze.getData(after).rank - 1
              } else if(!after) {
                  newRank = Blaze.getData(before).rank + 1
              } else {
                  newRank = (Blaze.getData(after).rank + Blaze.getData(before).rank)/2
              }
              Images.update({_id: Blaze.getData(el)._id}, {$set: {rank: newRank}})
        }
    })
}

Template.gallery.helpers({
    'getCurrentCategory': function() {
        return Template.instance().currentcategory.get();
    },
    'images': function (currentcategory) {
        if(currentcategory == 'all' || !currentcategory){
            return Images.find({},{sort: {rank: 1}});
        } 
        return Images.find({category:currentcategory});
    }
});
```

Comment: You cannot create a stackoverflow every 10 minuts, please take time to think about before ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132782/implementing-a-sortable-image-collection-not-working-in-meteor-js/34134733?noredirect=1#comment56058723_34134733. For your problem, just add console.log and add breakpoints and it will be easy fixed

Comment: @Ser suggestions accepted . And console.log has no data .  what needed is every category should have rank values independently . give a suggestion with piece of code . dono exactly how to start with it .

Comment: As I said before, the use of sortable (https://jqueryui.com/sortable/ ??) is not mandatory to achieve a sortable component in HTML. I trully don't know what's Blaze.getData do so I can't help --- I never had to do something as low level as this. Your code is also too much incomplete to let people understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to do this:

```
return Images.find({category:currentcategory},{sort:{rank:1}})
```

It's the same as your all category cursor but with the added sort specifier.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped. Good luck with your projects.